# Running Expo in development offline

Tags: react-native, expo

I looked over the docs, but cannot find a way to run Expo completely offline. I'm frequently in an area without a stable connection and this makes it exceptionally difficult to maintain a proper work flow.

I would have thought that `exp start --dev --lan` would enable offline development, but my expo client still fails on inability to connect to the expo servers.

Is there a truly offline mode for expo?

Comment: No, Internet is required the bundled files are downloaded from the expo web server.

Answer (score 7):

With the latest version of Expo (v32) you can run offline by using the following command

```
expo start --offline
```

Comment: Is it possible to run the app when your phone is offline? It doesn't work for me with just the offline-flag.

Answer (score 7):

In order to load the bundle

```
expo start --offline
```

will work. For running it on an Android device make sure to check if your device is listed in adb available devices by running

```
adb devices
```

You can make the connection with your adb device either by connecting it through wire or attaching the bridge wirelessly. [Instructions for help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you experience issues when testing offline try starting the Expo packager with the command yarn start --offline command and then in Expo dev tools set the connection type to "local".
2. Or you can also use expo start --offline.

Comment: I've started using expo start --offline as suggested but in iOS simulator the connection stays on, not really offline