# reset EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS to default IP?

Tags: expo

I was trying to run offline mode, as suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/72216728/5824563, by changing the EXPO_DEVTOOLS_LISTEN_ADDRESS & REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME. It was unsuccessful attempt…

How do I reset the IP address to default value? I cannot get my dev build on device to run